# I'm trying to make a system call in Ubuntu 12.04.1. I'm running into an error compiling my hello.c file

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm trying to make a system call in Ubuntu 12.04.1. I'm getting an error compiling my `hello.c` file:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) {
    printk("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It shows the error:

> `error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘long’ asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)`

Comment: "an issue" is somewhat light as problem description...

Comment: You are having "an issue". What kind of issue are you having? Any specific error message? Does your code summon unholy wailings of the departed?

Comment: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘long’
 asmlinkage long sys_hello(void)
            ^~~~
@RobertColumbia

Comment: I'm a bit confused here... This looks like something that's supposed to run in kernelspace, you're aware of that?

Comment: please give the solution of that issue ,@fvu

Comment: I thought `sys_write` is the system call that writes data to files...

Comment: now the question is clear ,please tell me the issue sir@RobertColumbia

Comment: It's not something that should be solved, you can answer with one of these two possibilities 1 - yes I am fully aware of that, I want to write something that runs inside the kernel, programs like insmod and lsmod have no secrets for me. or 2 - what's a kernel???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the system calls must be compiled into the kernel. You need to do this within the kernel build system.you cannot use it outside the kernel or shared object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to build a kernel module.  You need to do this within the kernel build system.  You cannot compile it as a regular application or shared object.  The easiest way probably is to patch the module into the Ubuntu kernel tree and build it using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515407/how-recipe-to-build-only-one-kernel-module#515408).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a system call in Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Assuming you mean you're trying to *create* a system call: kernel modules cannot add system calls. All system calls must be compiled into the kernel.